# How do folks keep offers in sync with market prices?

Tags: offer, trade

If I want to keep an offer for my asset USD@me near the current market rate for USD/XLM how would I go about that?

Do folks just add, remove and update offers non stop?
Doesn't that burn up XLM in transactions and fill up the ledger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no other way at the moment. If you would do 1 operation with base fee per second (which is most probably huge overkill) for one day it would cost you less than 1XLM.

Even at 1 ops/sec it shouldn't be serious problem to the network because it's able to run about 1000 ops/sec.

Also, fees are not going to be burn, but redistributed (to inflation pools).